# Primefaces dataTable filter works only once

Tags: primefaces

im using Primefaces 3.5 to create a dataTable with filters.

```
<h:form id="table">
     <div class="showRuleStyle">            
        <p:dataTable id="RuleTable" var="e" value="#{ruleListBean.rules}" filteredValue="#{ruleListBean.filteredRules}" styleClass="ruleTable"  paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="15" emptyMessage="Keine Einträge gefunden.">

            <p:column id="companyColumn" headerText="Name" filterBy="#{e.name}" filterOptions="#{ruleListBean.filterNameOptions}" >
                <h:outputText value="#{e.name}"></h:outputText>
            </p:column>

            ...

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>
                <h:commandButton id="DeleteRuleButton" value="Löschen" styleClass="buttondefault" action="#{ruleListBean.removeRule(e)}" update=":table"></h:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

Now, i get the table as intended and can choose an filter which updates the table. But now, if i try to choose a different filter or select the empty filter, nothing happens. If I click the button, it works again, which i think is because of the update of the form.

I tried to add

```
 <p:ajax event="filter" update=":table">
```

and other events, but it won't work.

Any suggestions?

Greets 
Alex

Answer (score 0):

What is the scope of the ruleListBean? I've tried your code and it worked as expected (without the p:ajax).

My ruleListBean is in view scope.

> It is suggested to use a scope longer than request like viewscope to
>   keep the filteredValue so that filtered list is still accessible after
>   filtering. (PrimeFaces User’s Guide pg. 135)

**NOTE**: Change h:commandButton to p:commandButton so that you can use the update feature.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. :) I got the problem now, the dataTable was in a second <h:form> (wrapper), which the filter updater could handle correctly.

Comment: This is not the case here. It even doesn't sort reversed. Also converting `allFoos()` to `allFoos` and then having getter/setter for `allFoos` didn't work here.